# upgrading latex pgfplots in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, latex

I have `pgfplots` for LaTeX installed but I'm not sure how to upgrade it to the newest version. When I do a search for `pgfplots`, it returns lots of folders... The sourceforge download has a zip file for the current version, but I'm not sure where to extract this. The current documentation hasn't been very helpful either, although maybe I'm just misunderstanding it.

Comment: How did you install `pgfplots`?

Comment: it seems to be part of the `texlive` package in the repository...maybe this question should be moved to the TeX stackexchange?

Comment: No, its fine here.  Have you tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it is still outdated. I've had a problem before with trying to upgrade texlive...a few years back. I remember I had to compile from source and it was fairly complicated. I was hoping I could somehow just update pgfplots without worrying about the rest of texlive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following along the lines of iSeth's suggestion, I looked into updating texlive.

I tried following the instructions of [this link](http://support.rstudio.org/help/kb/faq/installing-tex-live-2012-for-ubuntu-1204). On the `sudo apt-get upgrade` step, I got the following warning: *"The following packages have been kept back"* which then listed some texlive packages. So then I used `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` instead. Now texlive is upgraded and pgfplots seems to have been as well.

I'm still uncertain whether it is possible, and how, to individually upgrade pgfplots, but this solution solves my problems.